# Drawing power from load side of GFCI

Tags: electrical

I added a switched outdoor outlet and a switched outdoor light fixture to my garage, getting power from the load side of a GFCI outlet with a 12/2 romax. Everything works works fine, grounds are all connected and pigtailed to metal boxes, but my tester shows "open ground" at GCIF and new outdoor outlet. Ideas?

Comment: What type of tester? If it has a push to test the GFCI see if it will cause the GFCI to trip, if the ground is open the GFCI won’t trip with a tester but will using the test button on the GFCI itself.  In this case the GFCI is making the circuit safe but the ground wire is not connected someplace.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box of the GFCI you tapped power at please?

Comment: Had you checked the GFCI for ground prior to starting this project?  Maybe it *never* had a ground and you are just discovering this now...

Comment: It's actually my kid's garage 200 miles away. After I finished I tested with my old 2-prong tester and used outlets and light. All worked fine. Later the kid plugged in one of those three-light testers & showed open ground. I had added the GFCI outet drawing power from standard outlet with 12/2. Standard outlet is in plastic but I wirenut all grounds together. Kid (she) is not handy and afraid to use outlet because of test. I did ground GFCI on installing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the supply to the GFCI itself is what you need to check at both ends, since the tester is reading open ground there. Load wiring has nothing to do with that.

Presumably you didn't test before starting the work?

Comment: The kids sheetrocked after I added outlet, perhaps they wiggled something loose from the plastic outlet box feeding the GFCI. The test button on GFCI works properly, cutting power to everything it feeds.